# D3-tip undefined in line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

First of all; I know there are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711934/d3-d3-tip-doesnt-work-in-a-multiline-chart) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543756/d3-tip-not-working-for-a-line-chart) but none of them solved my problem.

My D3-Tip is not showing on my line chart. (It works on a map)

**JS**

```
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .html(function(d) {
        console.log(d); //undefined
        return "Sale : " + d.sale;
    });

svg.call(tip);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .on("mouseover", tip.show);
```

Nothing is shown and I got `undefined` inside my html function.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

In D3, the first argument (traditionally named `d`) refers to the data bound. So, when you write `console.log(d)`, you expect to see the data bound to that element. But, in your case, you have none!

A (partial) solution is changing this:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .on("mouseover", tip.show);
```

To this:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .on('mouseover', tip.show);
```

PS: I wrote *partial* because it will probably (I don't know your data) log an array of objects, not a single value corresponding to the position of the mouse over the line, which is what you seem to expect.

Comment: As you said I am getting an array that contains all my values. How can I show the value of my `y` where my mouse is ?

Comment: Well, that's a *different* question. Your specific problem here was, fortunately, solved. In StackOverflow, we deal with one question at a time, one problem per question. Thus, for the next step (*"how to show the y value of a line with mouseover"*), I suggest you post another question.

Comment: I do not want to be unkind but this not solve totally my question. The tooltip is showing now but not with the data that I wanted (`d.sale` as in the question). Anyway, thank for your help

Comment: I also don't want to be unkind but it *does* solve the present question: you had an *undefined*; I explained *why* you had it and *how* to solve it.